# Laravel: Hide attributes from model just in some routes

Tags: php, laravel, model, hide

how do I hide some attributes from the model in just some routes, for example:

I'm using protected $hidden to hide elements but this hide in all my functions or restful routes (index, show)

```
 $hidden = [
  'coachVisibility', 'thumbnail', 'studentVisibility',
  'isHTML', 'studentIndex', 'coachIndex',
  'isURL', 'source', 'path',
  'status', 'updateTime', 'isfolder',
  'parentResource', 'idModifierUser', 'idResourceType',
  'idCreatorUser', 'idCreationCountry', 'user',
  'country', 'resource'
];
```

I want to hide only in Index function but in show function I don't want to hide anything.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the `addHidden` method on the models:

```php
class UsersController
{
    public function index ()
    {
        return User::all()->each(function ($user) {
            $user->addHidden([.........]);
        });
    }
}
```

Once [this PR](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/13152) gets merged, you'll be able to call it directly on the collection:

```php
class UsersController
{
    public function index ()
    {
        return User::all()->makeHidden([.........]);
    }
}
```

---

According to your comment, you can keep all of those fields in the `$hidden` property of your model, and instead make them visible only in the `show` method:

```
public function show($id)
{
    return CTL_Resource::where('idResource', $id)
        ->with('tags', 'quickTags', 'relatedTo')
        ->firstOrFail()->makeVisible([
            'coachVisibility', 'thumbnail', 'studentVisibility'
        ]);
}
```

Comment: does this is correct?   `public function show($id)    {

    $resource = CTL_Resource::where('idResource', $id)->first();

    if ($resource)
      return response()->json(
        $resource->load('tags', 'quickTags', 'relatedTo')->addHidden(['coachVisibility', 'thumbnail', 'studentVisibility'])
      );
    else
      return response(null, 404);
  }`
because i'm getting a empty object :(  im using `$resource = CTL_Resource::where('idResource', $id)->first();` because im using UUIDs

Comment: @CanKerDiAlike - you get an empty object? What do you get without the `addHidden` call?

Comment: the entire object except the fields i'm hidding in my model with `proctected $hidden = ['some', 'data']`

Comment: @CanKerDiAlike - `addHidden(['coachVisibility', 'thumbnail', 'studentVisibility'])` hides those columns in your `show` method. Is that what you want?

Comment: ohh no no no, I want to show them, those columns are at this moment in my  `protected $hidden = ['coachVisibility', 'thumbnail', 'studentVisibility']`

Comment: Is it possible to hide or show certain attributes of a related model while querying for the related model but show/hide the default attributes when the related model is queried from another relationship or directly?

Answer (score 2):

Consider using Transformers to transform return data as you would like.

For eg:

Create an abstract Transformer:

```
namespace App\Transformers;

abstract class Transformer
{

    public function transformCollection(array $items)
    {
        return array_map([$this, 'transform'], $items);
    }

    public abstract function transform($item);
}
```

Then create custom transformers for each method if you like:

```
namespace App\Transformers;

use App\User;

class UserTransformer extends Transformer {

    public function transform($user) {

         return [
             'custom_field' => $user['foo'],
             'another_custom_field' => $user['bar']
             ...
        ];

    }
}
```

Then in your controller:

```
...

public function index(Request $request, UserTransformer $transformer)
{
    $users = User::all();

    return response()->json([
        'users' => $transformer->transformCollection($users->toArray())
     ], 200);
}
```

There are a couple of advantages to this:

1. You can show/hide data as you wish with specific transformers
2. In-case you decide to change the column names in your table, your transformers will ensure that clients getting your data will not break.

Comment: never heard about Transformers before, its a dependency/library or just have to create the class like your example?

Comment: @CanKerDiAlike Its not a library. Just create the classes yourself.

Comment: ok, give me a chance to try before select your answer. :) Thanks

Comment: Yeah, your answer works for me but another guy answered something more simple for my project, so I had to chose the other one. Thank you so much, Mr. Angad Dubey :) im so grateful for your time and knowledge :)